# How to script for syslog configuration(linux/AIX) ?

Tags: linux, syslog

I am new to scripting platform. Looking for creating a script in order to cover below scenarios. We have around 1000 servers and i wish to have a shell/ NSH script in place to get below details.

a. What syslog agent is configured(syslog-ng/rsyslog/syslogd) ?
b. How many servers have syslog configured and running ?
c. How many configured but not running?
d. How many does not have syslog configured ?

Any suggestion guys would be very helpful.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Using shell scripting here is possible but not easy... Based on the scale, I think you should start looking at **configuration management systems** (not easy either but will pay in the end), such [puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/) or [Chef](http://www.getchef.com/) manage packages across your env.

Comment: For the time being you may ignore the scale here. Can you assist me in building a shell script for this. To deal with scale we have Automation tool in place where in the script will execute against the target servers and fetch the required details. On the basis of which we will remediate the servers, if required.

Comment: You don't seem to have made any research or tried anything. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask